# Overload resolution ambiguity in third party java library called from kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, enums

I wrote a small program in Kotlin which uses library https://github.com/KaptainWutax/SeedUtils, specifically the Dimension enum https://github.com/KaptainWutax/SeedUtils/blob/master/src/main/java/kaptainwutax/seedutils/mc/Dimension.java

When I call e.g. `Dimension.OVERWORLD.name`, I get `Overload resolution ambiguity`.
I know what is the issue, the problem is that `enum Dimension` has `name` field, and the enum class itself has `name` field https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html

The question is, what can I do about it. My current approach is to fork this library and all other 4 libraries I use and depend on it, renaming `name` in that enum to something else, but I hate having to fork 5 repos to rename single field.

Is there any other way to get around this? Can I specify somehow which name should be use? Is there a way to remove this ambiguity somehow by telling the JVM what to do?

Or is there nothing to be done and naming enum field `name` is effective way to make it unusable by Kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround would be to write a helper method in Java, where it's unambiguous:

```cs
public class DimensionHelper {
    public static String getName(Dimension dimension) {
        return dimension.name;
    }
}
```

Then from Kotlin, you could call `DimensionHelper.getName()` whenever you wanted to access the name of a `Dimension`. You can then add an extension method in Kotlin:

```kotlin
fun Dimension.getName() = DimensionHelper.getName(this);
```

... which will allow you to just use `Dimension.OVERWORLD.getName()`.

It's far from ideal, but it *does* avoid having to fork.

(It's entirely possible that there's a Kotlin-specific way of doing this that I'm unaware of, of course.)

Comment: Can also be refined by then adding an extension method in kotlin: `fun Dimension.getName() = DimensionHelper.getName(this);` which allows you to call `Dimension.OVERWORLD.getName()`

Comment: @Lino: That sounds like a great idea - mind if I add it to the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Next to the workaround provided by [@JonSkeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63736399/5515060) there's possibly some other ways. The one I can think of is simply using the plain old java reflection api and a kotlin extension method:

```kotlin
private val nameField = Dimension::class.java.getDeclaredField("name")
fun Dimension.getName() = nameField.get(this) as String
```

Which allows you to call it like this:

```kotlin
val name = Dimension.OVERWORLD.getName()
```

Sadly this doesn't work with kotlin reflection, because then we'd run into the same error:

```kotlin
Dimension::name // Overload resolution ambiguity
```

This method using reflection can also be refined, by only looking the name up once. For that create a small helper object, containing a `Map<Dimension, String>`:

```kotlin
private object NameHolder {
    val dimensionToName = EnumMap<Dimension, String>(Dimension::class.java)
    init {
        val nameField = Dimension::class.java.getDeclaredField("name")
        for (dimension in Dimension.values()) {
            dimensionToName[dimension] = nameField.get(dimension) as String
        }
    }
}
```

and then change your extension method to this:

```kotlin
fun Dimension.getName() = NameHolder.dimensionToName[this]!!
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I can get java reflection such easily in kotlin. It's a pitty I can't accept both answers.

Comment: @MatějRačinský You're welcome. You just have to be careful when using java reflection on kotlin classes, or kotlin reflection on java classes. Because the class-definition may be different due to the nature of kotlin compiling down to java.

Comment: @MatějRačinský FYI, it's recommended not to accept any answer for a period of time, e.g. 24 hours, to give people in different time-zones a chance.  (I'm not saying that I'd have done better these answers, though!)

Comment: Oh, ok, I didn't know. I'll keep that in mind for next time.